# Generating Fieldset Groups Based on PDO Array Objects

Tags: php, html, arrays, fieldset

I am trying to create a simple questionnaire where PHP queries a MySQL DB, using PDO, to generate form items (questions and answer choices). The issue I am having is grouping answers, the solution I want is to group each question and answer choices by a fieldgroup, which would be generated from the PDO query results.

The DB is pretty simple, a table for questions (key|questions), a table for answers (key|answers), and the query just grabs questions, question key ids, answers, and answer ids, using PDO to place it all in an object. So far I can get the questions and answers to populate the page, but cannot get the fieldset to work correctly (it winds up nesting the questions and answers within eachother).

This is where I am generating the form:

```
<?php
 $qid = 0; 

 foreach ($allResults as $row) {

  if($qid !== $row->qid) {
   print "<h2>$row->question</h2>";
   $qid = $row->qid; //used to split questions while keeping answers
   print "<fieldset id='$row->qid'>"; //fieldset not working properly yet}

   print "<input type='radio'>$row->answer";
  }
?>
```

I have tried a few ways but can't seem to find away to get the answers to questions to be grouped separately with the questions

What it should be doing is allowing the user to select their answer to each question and submit them, which it technically does. However, as is, it nests each question recursively, so the question and answers for each subsequent question are nested within the previous question.

EDIT: I know I need to close each fieldset tag, but this is where I am having trouble. I have tried a few solutions, but the form is either still nested, or only the first answer is set correctly for each question.

Comment: Of course this winds up nesting, if you only ever output opening `<fieldset>` tags, but no matching closing ones _anywhere_.

Comment: Output an opening fieldset tag before the loop. Inside, when the question id changes AND it is not the initial change from 0 to an actual question id, output a closing and a new opening fieldset tag. Then output the data for the current question/answer. And a final closing tag after the loop.